# searching a data frame value through column names, and get the respective matching value column

Tags: r

```
    Date_Time   C   4700C   Put.15  4800C   Put.16  4900C   Put.17
1   20120531    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2   20120601 1445   4800    208 84.9    143.3   119.8   92  167
3   20120606 1100   4900    268.85  43  192 66.3    127 100
4   20120607 1500   5000    345 24  261 38.25   183 60.5
5   20120612 1515   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

I have the above sample data frame, here i wants to search the values of 1st row for C column in all the column names and get back the values of the matching column as the result.
For example <- wants to search the value of 2nd row C column which is 4900, in first all the column names, and once it's found 4900C, gives me the result as all the values in 4900C for 2nd row.

Pls help

Comment: This isn't very clear to me, can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Your data seems to be garbled. Can you include the output from `dput(variable_name)`, please?

Comment: well these are the option price data, here i am trying to find the value on the basis of C column, now i wants to find where the value of C lies on the column names say, i am searching for 4900 in column C,  from the column  heading 4900C,(which have the premium values) and wants to see the value from 4900C for 4900, which is 127.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been better if the delimiters in the data were clear.  For example `"Date_Time"` as column name could have elements `"20120531 NA"` as a string.

We remove the non-numeric substring from the `names` of the 'df1' (subset it based on 'j2') using `sub`, `match` with the 'C' to get the column index ('j1'), get a logical index based on the NA values ('i1'), then with `row/column` index, we extract the elements from the proposed columns (df1[-(1:3)]`) and assign it to a "NewCol".

```
j2 <- grep("\\d+C", names(df1))
j1 <-  match(df1$C, sub("\\D+", "", names(df1)[j2]))
i1 <- !is.na(j1)
df1$NewCol[i1] <- df1[j2][cbind((1:nrow(df1))[i1], j1[i1])]
df1
#       Date Time    C  4700C Put.15 4800C Put.16 4900C Put.17 NewCol
#1 20120531   NA   NA     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA
#2 20120601 1445 4800 208.00   84.9 143.3 119.80    92  167.0  143.3
#3 20120606 1100 4900 268.85   43.0 192.0  66.30   127  100.0  127.0
#4 20120607 1500 5000 345.00   24.0 261.0  38.25   183   60.5     NA
#5 20120612 1515   NA     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA
```

NOTE: Here I am assuming that 'Time' is the second column

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c(20120531L, 20120601L, 20120606L, 20120607L, 
20120612L), Time = c(NA, 1445L, 1100L, 1500L, 1515L), C = c(NA,  
4800L, 4900L, 5000L, NA), `4700C` = c(NA, 208, 268.85, 345, NA
), Put.15 = c(NA, 84.9, 43, 24, NA), `4800C` = c(NA, 143.3, 192, 
261, NA), Put.16 = c(NA, 119.8, 66.3, 38.25, NA), `4900C` = c(NA, 
92L, 127L, 183L, NA), Put.17 = c(NA, 167, 100, 60.5, NA)), 
.Names = c("Date", 
"Time", "C", "4700C", "Put.15", "4800C", "Put.16", "4900C", "Put.17"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: what does "\\D+" refer to ?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma  Refers to one or more non-numeric characters in the string. i.e. it removes the `C` from  `4900C` column name.

Comment: Thanks, one more question, how about if i have to include the next column value in the search as well. i.e everything remains same, but have to take the value from the next one column of the matching column.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma  It is not clear what you meant by `next column value`.

Comment: say the matching value + next column value, in this case, 4900C Put.17 and the results would be 143.3 119.8, 127,100.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma.  Okay, that is easy, `df1[j2][cbind((1:nrow(df1))[i1], j1[i1]+1)]`

Comment: Hi, well its, automatically assigning the output variable to V1, how can i assign the value of the next column output to a different variable name, so that it, does not overwrite the same variable every time. assigning the df1[j2][cbind((1:nrow(df1))[i1], j1[i1]+1)] output value to a different variable instead of v1. Thanks

Comment: @AbhishekSharma  You need to assign it to a new variable i.e. but before that it is better to keep a copy of the original dataset, `df2 <- df1` then do the assignment based on the original dataset columns,  `df2$NewCol2[i1] <-  df1[j2][cbind((1:nrow(df1))[i1], j1[i1]+1)]` and similarly do with `df2$NewCol[i] <- ...`

Comment: i have already assign, but as it's creating the variable internally, not able to do that, any hint please.Thanks.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma  Based on the example data I showed, it is working.  Please check the `str(df1)`.